# Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be binomial with, m=3 and unknown $\theta$. Show that $\theta_n^\prime=\frac{1}{3}\bar X_n$ is consistent

Tags: statistics

> Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be binomial, independent, random variables, with parameters $m=3$ and unknown $\theta$. Show that $\theta_n^\prime=\frac{1}{3}\bar X_n$.

I've already shown that this estimator is unbiased, so I want to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathrm{Var}(\theta_n^\prime)=0$ to show that it is consistent, since I assume this is easier then showing convergence in probability.

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathrm{Var}(\theta_n^\prime) &= \lim_{n\to\infty} \mathrm{Var}\Bigl( \frac{1}{3}\bar X_n \Bigr) \\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{9} \mathrm{Var}(\bar X_n)=\frac{1}{9}\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathrm{Var}(\bar X_n)\end{align}$$

So I need to know that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathrm{Var}(\bar X_n)=0$

Do I get that from independence? Im not sure how I can justify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- $\text{Var}\left(X_i\right)=3\theta(1-\theta)$ as this is a binomial distribution
- $\text{Var}\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i\right) = 3n\theta(1-\theta)$ as the sum of $n$ independent random variables
- $\text{Var}\left(\bar X_n \right) = \frac{3\theta(1-\theta)}{n}$ as  $\frac1{n^2}$ times the preceding variance
- $\text{Var}\left(\frac13 \bar X_n \right) = \frac{\theta(1-\theta)}{3n}$ as  $\frac1{3^2}$ times the preceding variance
- $\frac{\theta(1-\theta)}{3n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$